# SELECT For BizTalk Tracking Orchestration, Pipelines, Send Port Receive Locaton

Tags: select, biztalk, tracking

Could someone provide select (or method) to list any orchestrations, send port, etc. that have tracking option enabled?

I have a lot of applications deployed and I'd have to check them manually thus it is a lot of checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use;

`imgData` column of `StaticTrackingInfo` table for orchestrations

```
select * from StaticTrackingInfo where CONVERT(varbinary, imgData) <> 0x00000000
```

`nTracking` column of `bts_receiveport` table for receive ports

```
select * from bts_receiveport where nTracking <> 0
```

`nTracking` column of `bts_sendport` table for send ports

```
select * from bts_sendport where nTracking <> 0
```

Comment: select * from StaticTrackingInfo where CONVERT(varbinary, imgData) <> 0x00000000 shows some results but there is no tracking ticked on Admin Console, but these next 2 selects works great, thanks!

Comment: Because of `Track Events` part of orchestrations, imgData of StaticTrackingInfo always filling. If you want to see other selections. you can try `<> 0x13000000`

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

For this, querying the database wouldn't be my first option.  Instead...

I would write a program/script that queries exported binding files.  All the info you would need to report on this is contained right there, no joining or table mucking necessary.

Comment: Thanks for an answer but I prefer SQL as I'm native SQL Admin :)